# android: show dialog from service

Tags: android, dialog

I made an empty activity to only show a dialog called **DialogActivity**.

I have a tail service that shows a dialog by sending an intent to DialogActivity like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, DialogActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
                                          .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

when the app is closed it works properly, but when I open it and press home button then open the dialog (from the tail button) it show the main activity first then open the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found that my best answer is to use WindowManager instead of starting a new activity , kotlin code:

```
val wm = applicationContext.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888
        )
        params.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Translucent
```

then inflate and add a view to wm by :

```
wm.addView(view, params)
```